# Is an overhead of 1.5x typical for a HTTPS upload?

Tags: networking, google-chrome, speed, adsl, upload

I use Chrome to upload files to my Google Drive account. Today, I had to upload a 2+ GB file and since uploading typically saturates bandwidth, I decided to install the free version of NetBalancer and limit Chrome's upload rate.

It worked, but I did see one odd thing. For every MB of upload progress that Chrome reported, Netbalancer reported 2.5MB of upload for that instance of Chrome. Netbalancer doesn't *seem* to be in error since another third-party tool Network Activity Indicator reported similar gross upload traffic - no other networking apps were running at the time, except an idle Firefox browser window.

This machine is connected to the net via a router via an ADSL2+ modem synced upstream at 2048 kbps. So, the other odd thing is Netbalancer reporting Chrome's upload speed as 500-600 kB/s when not throttled.

Any idea if the numbers look right?

**Update**: It's definitely Chrome-related. When uploading through Firefox, Netbalancer shows the expected speed viz. 220-230 kB/s. I don't use Firefox for uploads because a couple of cores get maxed out and the temps start to climb, but that's a different question.

I only have the Google Doc extensions enabled in Chrome (48.0.2564.109 m). This is on Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit.

Comment: Something similar has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/548029/how-much-overhead-does-ssl-impose) and may already give you a chance to estimate the answer of your question (in short: No.)

Comment: Thanks. See edit. Definitely Chrome-specific. Any idea what it could be?

Comment: So, from the numbers, it looks like Chrome is uploading as fast as the other browsers (because 500/600 kb/s on a 2048 kbit/s link aren't possible), but for some reason $tools report a lot more traffic than actually happens - right?
The only thing I can think of is run wireshark, and try to see which bandwidth usage it reports, maybe following [this guide](http://blog.davidvassallo.me/2010/03/22/measuring-bandwidth-using-wireshark/). Besides that, I have no real idea at the moment.

Comment: Wireshark shows Chrome uploading at 4.9 mbps via `QUIC` with seq numbers forming a monotonically increasing series, whereas Firefox uploads via TCP (TLS).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the excess speed was due to use of Google's experimental [QUIC](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjrzsTVxPzKAhXBv44KHR7HAo0QFgglMAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.google.com%2Fa%2Fchromium.org%2Fdocument%2Fd%2F1lmL9EF6qKrk7gbazY8bIdvq3Pno2Xj_l_YShP40GLQE%2Fedit&usg=AFQjCNEzpy_1YE-9-z4nvkDMa5nY7Vqj3g&sig2=HiJDK3pyWayJjVuQpuH4OQ&bvm=bv.114195076,d.c2E) protocol. Disabling it via `about:flags --> Experimental QUIC protocol` got rid of the impossible speeds being reported.